# How WebBrowser control in .net handles ObjectForScripting

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms

As far as I know we can call C# function from Javascript, that is loaded inside a WebBrowser control, following code shows how I usually do it.

**Form1.cs**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form{
        private WebBrowser webBrowser1;
            public ApplicationWindow(){
               InitializeComponent();
                WebBrowser webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
                //some code follows
                webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = new ScriptManager();
                this.webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("file:///d:/ui/application.html");
            }
        }
    }
```

**ScriptManager.cs**

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication10 {
        [ComVisible(true)]
        public class ScriptManager{
            public string GetAllDomains(){
                string result=null;
                //does something;
                return result;
            }
        } 
    }
```

**application.html**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function () {
          var result = window.external.GetAllDomains();
          //it works but this is what puzzles me. 
       });
    </script>
```

**The questions that intrigues me are**

1. why we need ComVisible to be true for class whose object we are going to use as objectForScripting?
2. How Javascript object window.external has the same methods as in objectForScripting?
3. How they handle cross language type conversion?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why no one answered for so long. The answer to all your questions is COM - Component Object Model.

Windows is providing ability (using COM) for classes and functions from one program (exe) to be accessible outside the exe.

So

1) why we need ComVisible to be true for class whose object we are going to use as objectForScripting?

-> This tells windows to make the class and its methods visible to the webbrowser.

2) How Javascript object window.external has the same methods as in objectForScripting?

-> The javascript is calling methods of the class made visible in above answer.

3) How they handle cross language type conversion?

-> COM handles the types internally so methods in one programming language can be called from another programming language.